# ExpressionEngine Installation Issues: Database Connection Error on Localhost

Tags: mysql, localhost, expressionengine

Running into an odd issue with a getting a successful localhost install of ExpressionEngine 2.5.3.

I am able to run the ExpressionEngine Installation and Update Wizard where server settings, database setting and admin account information is entered. So the Apache side is working as expected, or so I assume.

The issue crops up when I click on the Install ExpressionEngine button — the point where the installer starts working it's magic — get this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: controllers/wizard.php
Line Number: 1532
```

For the SQL Server Address, Username and Password, I am using the same values I have used in the past: localhost for the server address, root for the username and root for the password.

Those credentials work when used with Sequel Pro 0.9.9.1.

Permissions on config.php and database.php — both empty files — are set to 666, as suggested by the ExpressionEngine installation documentation.

I am trying this on a MacBook Air running 10.8.2 with the built-in Apache and MySQL running via XAMPP. I am using VirtualHost X to so http://baseline.loc/ points to baseline.loc in my Sites folder. There are no other instances of Apache or MySQL running.

I am not well versed debugging server issues but I am comfortable working in the terminal.

Any ideas what I should be looking at to figure out why this usually basic stage of a new project has become a stumbling block?

Comment: can you try the process over with a fresh DB?

Comment: Created a new database (basecamp_alpha) and same error message.

Comment: Just for kicks and giggles have you tried the server wizard?

Comment: Nah, I know EE runs on this machine. Turned out using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost was all I needed.

Comment: Off topic, but I find this [permissions setting script](http://quickshiftin.com/blog/2013/10/expression-engine-permissions-utility/) handy anytime I install or migrate Expression Engine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've had issues before using localhost as the host. Does 127.0.0.1 work for you?

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar in OSX using mamp, simply changed the folder permission of the web folder to everyone read/write via finder and that did the trick

Comment: Attempted this but no luck. However, Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost worked.